# PHP not reading cookie value set when page was loaded

Tags: php

I am setting a cookie based on a GET variable in the URL:

```
if (isset($_GET['this'])) {
  setcookie('this', $_GET['this'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
}

echo $_COOKIE['this'];
```

So, if I load the page:

`mypage.php?this=that`

The page echos nothing. But if I refresh the page again, it reads the cookie and echos it's value.

I think the page is outputting before the cookie data is set and able to be read. Any ideas how to correct this?

Comment: The page needs to reload before you can get the cookie(). Do a redirect to self then read cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, Brian makes a good point also, the best "pattern" is to set a value into session and then return a 302 (redirect) to the next view - for example a login page will process the creds, set the session and then redirect to a dashboard page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the cookie val is not available until the next request...  it is PHP functionality. If you need to output it in this request, you could try echoing the GET value:

```
<?php

//imaginary code setting coookie
$_COOKIE['this'] = $_GET['this'];


//simplified pseudo code
if(isset($_COOKIE['this'])){
    echo $_COOKIE['this'];
}
else
{
   echo $_GET['this'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

that's exactly how cookies work:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

> Common Pitfalls:
>
> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was
>   successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before
>   the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A
>   nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling
>   print_r($_COOKIE);.